# ¿Como subir multiple información a un mismo campo en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esto

```
$query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

     while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $filaid = $fila['id'];
            $noma = $fila['Nombre'];
            $totalpeso = $fila['peso']*$cab;
            $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;
            $totalproductosvendi = $fila['Cantidad']-$cab;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo'<td></td>';
            echo '<center><td>';
            echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" 
   value="'.$cab.'""></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';
            echo '<td>$'.$fila['Precio'].'</td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            //echo '<td><input type=hidden 
   value='.$fila['Cantidad'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>$'.number_format($total,2).'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            //echo $totalpeso;
            //echo '<a href=functions/check3.php?a='.$i.' 
        class=borrar>Borrar</a>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';


            $suma += $total;

                }
    }       
}
```

lo que necesito es hacer un insert en una tabla X, pero de los datos que vienen de la consulta, ahorita lo hago y solo toma al ultimo dato de la consulta mas no a todos lo que me genera es decir me genera 5 productos al consulta y solo de inserta el ultimo pero no los .
Vi que se pone INSERT INTO ha (valorx,valory) VALUES ((1,2),(1,2)) pero no se como hacerlo pasando una variable que se repite en el bucle en este caso tomando el id ($fila['id']) para que se ponga el nombre del producto

```
 tabla x 

 Id Nombre Cantidad id_factura

//nombre es del producto y cantidad igual dados por $fila['Nombre'] y
// $cab el id_factura viene de otra tabla
```

pero como digo solo se inserta el ultimo producto no todos los que tengo en la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu bucle `while` realiza la INSERT que necesites. Por cada registro que lea lo irá insertando:

```
INSERT INTO X (Nombre, Cantidad)
VALUES ($noma, $totalproductosvendi);
```

Por cierto, estás metiendo los resultados en variables `$noma = $fila['Nombre'];` y luego no los estás utilizando.

Puedes cambiar `echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';` por `echo '<td>'.$noma.'</td>';`